# How to set UIWindow property in Swift

Tags: swift

Ive been trying to make a simple change in UIWindow bounds in Swift.  So far I have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    //SHIFT EVERYTHING DOWN - THEN UP IN INDIV VCs IF ios7>
    var device:UIDevice=UIDevice()
    var systemVersion:String=device.systemVersion
    println(systemVersion)
    //Float(systemVersion)

    if (systemVersion >= "7.0") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
        self.window.setClipsToBounds = true // --> Member doesnt exist in UIWindow
        self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    //}

    let ok = true
    println("Hello World")
    return true
}
```

but I get:

UIWindow does not have member named at each self.window.property setter line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `self.window` is an Optional. You first have to ["unwrap" it](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432). You also need to use `clipsToBounds` not `setClipsToBounds`.:

```
if let window = self.window {
    window.clipsToBounds = true
    window.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: window.frame.size.width, height: window.frame.size.height);
    window.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.size.width, height: window.frame.size.height);
}
```

**Note**: I also updated CGRectMake to the preferred Swift way of creating CGRect using the CGRect initializer instead of the global `CGRectMake` function.

Answer (score 2):

In the AppDelegate class, window is an optional variable. You need to force unwrap the variable with !.

For example,

```
self.window!.clipsToBounds = true
```

If you aren't familiar with how optionals in Swift work, check out documentation from Apple about them.

Comment: Wow!  And here I thought Swift was supposed to make coding more efficient.  Thanks!